# Erro ao importar registros do banco pra gráfico

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mysqli, highcharts

No meu sistema antigo eu tinha um gráfico hightcharts que importa os valores de registros da minha tabela do banco de dados, porém, ao usar o mesmo modelo em outro sistema, começou a aparecer o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: SCJan in C:\Program Files
> (x86)\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\Sis_Tam\indicadorS.php
>
> Notice: Undefined index: SDJan in C:\Program Files
> (x86)\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\Sis_Tam\indicadorS.php
>
> Notice: Undefined index: SEJan in C:\Program Files
> (x86)\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\Sis_Tam\indicadorS.php

Segue o código da minha página com o gráfico:

**Parte em php responsável por fazer a importação:**

```
    <script src="../../code/modules/series-label.js"></script>
    <script src="../../code/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <div id="container"></div>
    <?php
    /*-------------------------------------Janeiro ---------------------------------*/
    require_once("strcon.php");
    $totaSAJ = 0;
    $totaSBJ = 0;
    $totaSCJ = 0;
    $totaSDJ = 0;
    $totaSEJ = 0;

    $SAJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Serviço A' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
    $SBJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SBJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Serviço B' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
    $SCJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SCJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Serviço C' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
    $SDJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SDJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Serviço D' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
    $SEJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SEJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Serviço E' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
    
    $consultasaj = mysqli_query($strcon, "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Serviço A' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'");
    $consultasbj = mysqli_query($strcon, "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SBJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Serviço B' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'");
    $consultascj = mysqli_query($strcon, "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SCJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Serviço C' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'");
    $consultasdj = mysqli_query($strcon, "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SDJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Serviço D' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'");
    $consultasej = mysqli_query($strcon, "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SEJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Serviço E' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'");

    if ($consultasaj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAJ)) {
        if ($rowsaj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasaj)) {
            $totaSAJ = $rowsaj['SAJan']; //Seta o total
        }
        mysqli_free_result($consultasaj);
    } else {

    }
    if ($consultasbj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SBJ)) {
        if ($rowsbj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasbj)) {
            $totaSBJ = $rowsbj['SBJan']; //Seta o total
        }
        mysqli_free_result($consultasbj);
    } else {

    }
    if ($consultascj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SCJ)) {
        if ($rowscj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultascj)) {
            $totaSCJ = $rowsbj['SCJan']; //Seta o total
        }
        mysqli_free_result($consultascj);
    } else {

    }
    if ($consultasdj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SDJ)) {
        if ($rowsdj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasdj)) {
            $totaSDJ = $rowsbj['SDJan']; //Seta o total
        }
        mysqli_free_result($consultasdj);
    } else {

    }
    if ($consultasej = mysqli_query($strcon, $SEJ)) {
        if ($rowsej = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasej)) {
            $totaSEJ = $rowsbj['SEJan']; //Seta o total
        }
        mysqli_free_result($consultasej);
    } else {

    }
```

**Parte responsável pelo gráfico:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        Highcharts.chart('container', {

            title: {
                text: 'Indicador anual de serviços'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: [{
                categories: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
                crosshair: true
            }],

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            },


            series: [{
                name: 'Serviço A',
                data: [<?php echo $rowsaj['SAJan'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaf['SAFev'];?>,<?php echo $rowsamar['SAMar'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaabr['SAAbr'];?>, <?php echo $rowsamai['SAMai'];?>, <?php echo $rowsajun['SAJun'];?>, <?php echo $rowsajul['SAJul'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaago['SAAgo'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaset['SASet'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaout['SAOut'];?>, <?php echo $rowsanov['SANov'];?>, <?php echo $rowsadez['SADez'];?>]
            }, {
                name: 'Serviço B',
                data: [<?php echo $rowsbj['SBJan'];?>,<?php echo $rowsbf['SBFev'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbmar['SBMar'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbabr['SBAbr'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbmai['SBMai'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbjun['SBJun'];?>,<?php echo $rowsbjul['SBJul'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbago['SBAgo'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbset['SBSet'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbout['SBOut'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbnov['SBNov'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbdez['SBDez'];?>]
            }, {
                name: 'Serviço C',
                data: [<?php echo $rowscj['SCJan'];?>, <?php echo $rowscf['SCFev'];?>, <?php echo $rowscmar['SCMar'];?>, <?php echo $rowscabr['SCAbr'];?>, <?php echo $rowscmai['SCMai'];?>, <?php echo $rowscjun['SCJun'];?>, <?php echo $rowscjul['SCJul'];?>, <?php echo $rowscago['SCAgo'];?>, <?php echo $rowscset['SCSet'];?>, <?php echo $rowscout['SCOut'];?>, <?php echo $rowscnov['SCNov'];?>, <?php echo $rowscdez['SCDez'];?>]
            }, {
                name: 'Serviço D',
                data: [<?php echo $rowsdj['SDJan'];?>, <?php echo $rowsdf['SDFev'];?>, <?php echo $rowsdmar['SDMar'];?>, <?php echo $rowsdabr['SDAbr'];?>, <?php echo $rowsdmai['SDMai'];?>, <?php echo $rowsdjun['SDJun'];?>, <?php echo $rowsdjul['SDJul'];?>, <?php echo $rowsdago['SDAgo'];?>, <?php echo $rowsdset['SDSet'];?>,<?php echo $rowsdout['SDOut'];?>, <?php echo $rowsdnov['SDNov'];?>, <?php echo $rowsddez['SDDez'];?>]
            }, {
                name: 'Serviço E',
                data: [<?php echo $rowsej['SEJan'];?>, <?php echo $rowsef['SEFev'];?>, <?php echo $rowsemar['SEMar'];?>, <?php echo $rowseabr['SEAbr'];?>, <?php echo $rowsemai['SEMai'];?>, <?php echo $rowsejun['SEJun'];?>,<?php echo $rowsejul['SEJul'];?>,<?php echo $rowseago['SEAgo'];?>, <?php echo $rowseset['SESet'];?>, <?php echo $rowseout['SEOut'];?>, <?php echo $rowsenov['SENov'];?>, <?php echo $rowsedez['SEDez'];?>]
            }],

            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        tickInterval: 1,
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'horizontal',
                            align: 'center',
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }

        });
        </script>
```

**AS LINHAS QUE DÃO ERRO SÃO:**

> $totaSCJ = $rowsbj['SCJan'];
>
> $totaSDJ = $rowsbj['SDJan'];
>
> $totaSEJ = $rowsbj['SEJan'];

OBS: Eu fiz um código igual ao do mês de janeiro para os outros meses, por isso aparecem mais meses no gráfico, mas como todos dão o mesmo erro só achei necessário colocar o código de um dos meses pra facilitar o entendimento.

Eu preciso muito resolver esse problema hoje ainda, então se puderem me ajudar eu ficaria muito grata. :)

-------------------------------- ATUALIZAÇÃO -------------------------------

TODOS OS ERROS FORAM RESOLVIDOS QUANDO EU COLOQUEI UM ISSET ANTES DAS `$ROW $totaSCJ = ISSET($rowsbj['SCJan']);` MAS AINDA ASSIM O GRÁFICO NÃO APARECE NA TELA.

Comment: mariana coloca valores que nao vem do banco de dados nessas variaveis, e vc ja consegue mapear aonde esta o erro. eu to achando que nao esta vindo nada

Comment: Todos os erros resolveram quando eu coloquei um ISSET antes das row, mas mesmo assim o gráfico não aparece

Comment: ja verificou se esta vindo dados nessas variaveis?

Comment: Não. Mas mesmo quando eu deixo o gráfico sem o php, o gráfico que estava abrindo antes não abre.

Comment: vem pro chat [link] (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha)